# Appending structure to create new set of structure if exists

Tags: coldfusion

I am checking the form value and if the different form value exists in the structure, it should append it else, it should create that session structure. With the following code, i am trying to do it:

```
<cfif session.box_status.partner_id NEQ "">
        <cfset session.box_status.partner_id = StructAppend(session.box_status.partner_id,FORM.partner_id,'No') />
     <cfelse>
        <cfset session.box_status.partner_id = FORM.partner_id />
     </cfif>
```

Apparently above code does not checking if the same value is existing in the form structure or not, but it is also giving me an error:

```
You have attempted to dereference a scalar variable of type class java.lang.String as a structure with members.
```

**Update #1**
[image]

> http://screencast.com/t/G50k5RCXROWQ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are treating session.box_status.partner_id as a struct, but it is a simple value. Session is a struct, but the value you are particularly working with is a simple string. Just use listAppend.

After talking more w/ voyeger in comments, we figured out he wanted an array of structs. So he should begin by initializing the value as an array:

```
session.box_status = arrayNew(1);
```

or

```
session.box_status = [];
```

And he can then just append a struct.

```
newData = { // keys here };
arrayAppend(session.box_status, newData);
```

Comment: Thanks @Ray, I used List Append, but that appended the value inside the structure, i want to create a new structure of the same session, probably i think i had communicated the questions wrongly, Update #1 Added Screenshot with your results:

Comment: I'm sorry - I don't quite understand what you mean. You want a new structure? So you want box_status to be 'reset' perhaps?

Comment: yes, i want a new structure, i mean box_status can contain multiple structures like the one i have shown in the screenshot, i can contain n numbers. I hope i made my question quite a bit clear now

Comment: So is it fair to say that box_status should be an array then? If it can contain multiple sets of values then maybe an array of structs is what you want?

Comment: You would begin by making it an array when the sesison starts. session.box_status  = arrayNew(1) (or []). Then you just append to the array.

Comment: put your answer in an answer box, so i can accept, Thanks ray for guidance